# Как загрузить определённый текст из файла

Tags: c#, rsa

Изначально я генерирую ключ приватный:

```
private void GenNewKEYS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Button
{
   int i = 0;
   using (RSA rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048)) // Generate a new 2048 bit RSA key
   {
      i++;
      string publicKeyXML = rsa.ToXmlString(true); // Открытый ключ RSA
      string PrivateKeyXML = rsa.ToXmlString(false); // Закрытый ключ RSA
      string fname = Path.GetFileName($"PrivateKey_#_{i}"); // Тут рандомно сохраняется
        
      RSAKeys key = new RSAKeys();
      key.PublicKeyXML = publicKeyXML;
      key.PrivateKeyXML = PrivateKeyXML;
      key.FileName = fname;
          
      rsaKeys.Add(key);
      File.WriteAllText(fname+".priv", PrivateKeyXML);
      // File.WriteAllText(fname+".pub", publicKeyXML);
   }
}
```

Мне нужно просто сохранить как-то публичный ключ для дальнейшего заполнения `RSAKeys` когда перезапустил приложение (если рядом в папке есть ключи эти, то подгрузить их и использовать уже существующие данные от ключей) Если нет, то создать новые...

Изначально я сохраняю как приватный так и публичный ключ в папку.
Но использовать два файла не выгодно, их получается очень много если каждый раз с одной генерации получается два файла. Но мне подсказали что можно использовать один файл приватный (privateKey.key) и использовать его, но как мне получить из него публичный ключ? В нём же хранится как приватный так и публичный ключ для использования.

В файле приватного ключа есть строки:

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>z3j2ZZstqQ7zHOYMkHjBZwgOyuH6QCeebZV2qW0geWCjJU7Dm60GjeMkh+bmcdOFAzFf8YO7eamuIPsShqlOVsu/E+tYSI65QydNXbGB9m5KLoYWSVjFWrErch5rqOG23DM61oT080IIUp4/WQEWC9ZHCESsM4bipUMfjC5bWJTvOtqa62uh+qUcaI92oKzR1vSXe+hhcHU9NhhO+ge8syFtlFBMGwMvsDkG1zrn35QkyZ49ErbXPS9EqCBvR8z13oRXsuH62ZFXS5/c/jsaI/Lbe7sIdrZauF2kBqgQFq9ji6aPfTCr4fHkx5gA4UTkplpxVWGcEO3NS3wU1KtkQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>0D8XTxeKW+5rqM2gexibNHbWE0RF39tJbDmLi6wfD3bjUs2akwYD6QzHX05SXOyRDf2SlOE2ZmYlgy40r2jB6Y2cn4VAYMfJeNMQmG0CHTa0aHdDeX/UxRiLnbTEA7pZ2H4h/Ozetw/U4qc0VNmxK3DxloEaAELKNeKZiif30X8=</P><Q>/wxwF1HJ24fTaRSBNa5kXsXkAqsTIVtB1IveGb9lYkXc9nSXwfFToR8ctMtFQq6gfjQ+dOthJvuTSJZ1glkzOHi11Y3sF+xSGfFR4UDoh1v7kjuB98rlDOHwITa6JsHJ4TSBjjsj25Fzaw6BrWHKidYlI55ywfad8IIIgDpl6O8=</Q><DP>dSI3uy4zjfgyqFVZIkQ58K2zRk0NvJe82doYauza37jwrr+lZXNpuamNb0c/vrL1+FecHo/7KGfmS74utkeHYxZbdcLe7lESOxsFZ6dRHBuMKIKE+o9zn5Vp2sA1zR8BsGtqNLkLoQ6PoRmJrvxv0k6KJSzi8iifUuXtlS9cDoM=</DP><DQ>/S07l+p4lpOeKRFRshgLSojmbj+kHdiY4IR3VNfJrGPtlDjo7HzCp45a0J13g1oVtzHlTerZ5fiVm9i/jUU+szAgUH0xgA328gm7Xf8w1C1a7S5lNbUS6lbeKBpLb22vGP8mHCpYzfz0tbEQySvqAimxdEo1YJWO8tAh4CgYQcE=</DQ><InverseQ>RPI3fA/dvehXz7D9hoXR/WJZ/sFcuNKZLUym7U27tUeMiVcZ03GqnsO8u75d/e/HBGjH/rnpJ9/7858L1850bWAwufaNVhJfx00F7dezSOZu9VaDV+Cx8/kEskEAu49Ma8AWLr7SeBEtnP3KQaCMKQ3AUn4SyPDXiedRFX8L+lw=</InverseQ><D>clL0ZcXE7VPv06Rq3F7EC2ZRuGkvVix6JxVbT8V5pw5iFrdwuG42HjA37JkwM9fIZXH4LoVj2qH7grdnMBpoqydcx7ncDyc+jtKZmkldrBvEVPXezti0NawEvsI2kw4XFLqeoJ2dSVu0vCt+ahp/7lwA3Wg4FWctc/rXzH1q4COMN7NmJilIXFtG8W5jzrm1oUYoQEQOCDhKBa0eHyGd46dwdIhJoNZ1cRnuINuoHMJ0gDIEszqxoNwSBuTQg9VVxgvuqxj12ID30wyxrcZWvTq8mTWtM/hGUiAqxrFUj4/FN2f0IyK2alN+AowtCTpoVHGp+k+cF6J7tP8x8Mn5ZQ==</D></RSAKeyValue>
```

Как мне можно загрузить публичный ключ из файла в отдельную переменную и в конце добавить  а приватный текст пропустить?
Конечная строка для открытого ключа: `</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>`

Comment: Я видимо не угадал, что вам нужно и с какой целью. Ответ был удалён. Переформулируйте вопрос понятнее. Если нужно быдо извлечь публичный ключ из файла приватного ключа отдельно, то я давал ответ, но вы сказали что надо не это. А что надо получить, и в каком формате?

Comment: М-м-м... Вопрос сводится к тому, как распарсить xml?

Comment: @aepot, видимо я что-то не так понял изначально. Но у Вас в том ответе было применено `RSACryptoServiceProvider` а мне нужно вот такое вот. (Переформулию сейчас вопрос)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, xml не использую. По сути мне нужно просто как текстовик, в котором хранятся string данные от ключей

Comment: В вопросе показан именно XML.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, я просто думаю если речь идёт о парсинге, то скорее всего потребуется какая-то библиотека что-ли?? А мне просто нужно достать текст определённый из файла и использовать его в качестве публичного ключа для RSA.

Comment: To**Xml**String, PublicKey**XML**, PrivateKey**XML**

Comment: `key.PrivateKeyXML` в вашем случае содержит оба ключа. То есть проинициализировав провайдер этой строкой вы сможете и шифровать и расшифровывать. То есть в данном случае публичный ключ отдельно не нужен вообще. Но вы так и не ответили, ЗАЧЕМ ВАМ ПУБЛИЧНЫЙ КЛЮЧ. Для заполнения структуры данных - не ответ.

Comment: @aepot, так вот именно для этого и нужно, для заполнения  данных.  Я просто хочу в каждую переменную разделить данные от файла `PrivateKeyXML` чтобы в одном хранился ключ приватный, а в другой переменной публичный ключ.

Comment: _А мне просто нужно достать текст определённый из файла и использовать его в качестве публичного ключа для RSA._ - я восстановил ответ, в ответе `string publicKey` это то что вам нужно. Вы даже не попробовали проверить, а сразу сделали вывод, что это не то. Обновил ответ.

Comment: `var param = rsa.ExportParameters(true); var exponent = Convert.ToBase64String(param.Exponent);` Далее `exponent` можно сохранить в файл. Это то, что нужно?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov экспонента это константа 65537 она же AQAB в Base64.

Comment: @aepot - у автора в самом конце вопроса именно это указано как желаемый результат, насколько я понял.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov верно, но речь про публичный ключ. Автор просто криво скопировал то что ему нужно, это очевидно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В XML текст приватного ключа `RSACryptoServiceProvider` [сохраняет](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.toxmlstring) **оба ключа**, а не только приватный.

> When you pass `true` to the `ToXmlString` method, the resulting XML string takes the following form:

```xml
<RSAKeyValue>
   <Modulus>…</Modulus>
   <Exponent>…</Exponent>
   <P>…</P>
   <Q>…</Q>
   <DP>…</DP>
   <DQ>…</DQ>
   <InverseQ>…</InverseQ>
   <D>…</D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

> When you pass `false` to the `ToXmlString` method, the resulting XML string takes the following form:

```xml
<RSAKeyValue>
   <Modulus>…</Modulus>
   <Exponent>…</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

`Modulus`+`Exponent` - это публичный ключ.

Достать из приватного XML публичный ключ можно вот так:

```
private string GetPublicKey(string privateKey)
{
    using (RSA rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
    {
        rsa.FromXmlString(privateKey);
        return rsa.ToXmlString(false);
    }
}
```

Использовать так

```
string publicKey = GetPublicKey(privateKey);
```

Comment: не не не, не из RSACrypto, а именно из файла `privatekey.xml`

Comment: @ZuPooSwitch так а зачем это делать? И почему этот код для извлечения публичного ключа не подходит?

Comment: Вы просто говорили что можно загрузить публичный ключ из одного файла приватного ключа, там же хранится как приватный так и публичный ключ же. Вот и я подумал как можно загрузить часть текста из файла, один прочитать полностью а другой частью.

Comment: @ZuPooSwitch я говорил, что зря храните публичный отдельно, лишние файлы, а сейчас показал как при необходимости этот публичный ключ извлечь отдельно.

Comment: так он у меня и был отдельно, изначально я генерировал 2 файла (приватный и публичный) хранились они в папке. Так было проще - да, но и я подумал что файлов действительно много, потому генерирую только приватный файл. Вот и подумал что можно сохранить только приватный ключ, от него извлечь публичный ключ и не использовать отдельный файл (public.xml).

Comment: @ZuPooSwitch так ответ именно про это. В любой момент из файла с двумя ключами вы можете получить только публичный, и в ответе показано, как. В файл приватного ключа сохраняются оба ключа, а не только приватный. Поэтому смысла хранить публичный отдельно нет.

Comment: @ZuPooSwitch обновил ответ с объяснением, так понятнее?

Comment: я вот только что попробовал использовать так как у Вас написано, но мне выдаёт ошибку при загрузке приватного ключа с данным методом. [Ошибка](https://ibb.co/VMWhTK5)

Comment: @ZuPooSwitch у вас ошибка, перепутаны ключи в вашем коде `string publicKeyXML = rsa.ToXmlString(true); // Открытый ключ` true - это приватный ключ. Почему исключение, видимо потому что вы передаете некорректные данные в метод.

Comment: всё! Я разобрался, спасибо большое!!! Моя не внимательность меня и погубила)) Я просто не читал файл как файл, а загружал просто как строку и выводило ошибку. Кстати, теперь понял что можно и не хранить в переменных данные от файлов а просто грузить сам файл и использовать его благодаря Вашему методу. Почему я сразу не допёр :(

Comment: @ZuPooSwitch приватный ключ нельзя никуда передавать, помните об этом, иначе весь смысл RSA пропадет.